# How would you make Flask(Python) recognize index.html for ALL static folders by default?

Tags: python, flask

I want to make flask serve index.html for ALL folders in my static directory.
`tree` displays this:

```
static/
├── contact
│   └── index.html
├── index.html
└── notoken
    └── index.html
```

I want `/notoken` or `/contact` to display what's in `/notoken/index.html` and `/contact/index.html`.
P.S: I DO NOT want to serve them using render_template or send_from_directory or anything like that because I don't want to do that for EVERY single file/folder

Answer (score 1):

Write a view that captures a path. Serve the `index.html` file under that path. Paths that don't exist will 404.

```
@app.route('/pages/')
@app.route('/pages/<path:path>')
def page(path=''):
    html = os.path.join(path, 'index.html')
    return app.send_static_file(html)
```

Generate urls with `url_for`. You can only call that in templates though, not in static files.

```
url_for('page', path='contact')
# /page/contact
```

The `page` prefix is added to distinguish it from other URLs, otherwise there may be conflicts since `path` is essentially a wildcard match.